# Visual Basic random number generation

Tags: .net, vb.net

Will this code produce a number from 1 to 100, or from 1 to 99?

```
 Dim oneDieGenerator As New Random
 FirstDieLabel.Text = oneDieGenerator.Next(1, 100)
```

Comment: Why not look it up all by yourself [Random.Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** 1 to 99.

**Long answer with explanation:** An extract from MSDN documentation for [Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides clarification on how parameters should be used:

- minValue: The **inclusive** lower bound of the random number returned.
- maxValue: The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

Notice I highlighted words **inclusive** and **exclusive** - these are important. The above simply means that result of

```
oneDieGenerator.Next(1, 100)
```

Would be anything from 1 to a 100, but not including 100. Now if you look at return value of this method, you notice it's an integer, meaning not including 100 is the same as 99. BTW, documentation for `Return Value` says exactly this:

- A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue.

Ok, maybe not clearly enough. Regardless, you can infer this behavior from examples - see below on the [MSDN page I linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- 20 random integers from 1 to 10 <-- to generate them, they used `rnd.Next(1, 11)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code will produce a number from 1 to 99**

You could find out yourself what number your code will produce by setting the minimum value to 0 and the maximum value to 1 and run the code multiple times to see if it will give you the number 1.